# Right justifying numbers in an input field

Tags: html

Using this example, how would I right justify numbers in the input fields?

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
Taxes: <input type="number" name="Taxes" value="" /><br />
Shipping: <input type="number" name="shipping" value="" align="right" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> 

<p>Click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "html_form_action.asp".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 26):

Style your input with:

```
text-align: right;
```

This will right justify all text in your input.

Comment: When I change the style it justifyies right the fieldname and input field, when I want to justify the text WITHIN the input field.

Comment: <html>
<body>
<p style="text-align:right">    
 <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
  Taxes: <input type="number" name="Taxes" value="" /><br />
  Shipping: <input type="number" name="shipping" value="" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form> 
</p>     
 <p>Click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "html_form_action.asp".</p>
    
</body>
</html>